# File transfer from and to BQ Ubuntu phone

Tags: files, phone, transfer

My ubuntu (14.04 LTS) laptop does not automatically pick up my BQ ubuntu phone when connecting with a USB cable.

Is it possible to transfer files between laptop and phone by cable and how is it done?

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, please [write an answer](/help/self-answer) explaining the solution and accept it instead of editing the answer into the question. Follow [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed instructions per http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702 as suggested by Aimar

Ubuntu 14.04 now recognised the BQ Ubuntu phone and files may be transferred

Answer (score 1):

If it is connecting your Phone to Laptop, then, try the following:

- Goto Dash, and Type Disks and open it.
- If you can see your Phone Connected to it, then, select it, goto options and **Mount** it.

**Edit :**
If The Laptop detects it, then only you can connect with it.

Comment: The phone is not accessible through 'Disks', i.e. it is not picked up or recognised as a device.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very specific needs, you could just use gMTP (it's in the repositories).

It might come in handy to zip files/folders before transfer (ubuntu touch is able to unzip).